# Free jquery based scheduler to use in enterprise projects

Tags: gratis, open-source, jquery, scheduling, saas

I've been struggling to find a component like fullcalendar / dhtmlxScheduler/ jqwidgets to use in a saas application with free license, any tips? My client thinks that the fullcalendar(Scheduler) $480 license price  is a bit high and need it to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Essential Schedule for JavaScript](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/javascript/ejschedule) is an option if your client qualifies for the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense).

[image: Schedule Syncfusion]

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thanks!!! My client was aproved and I'm already working on Essential Schedule for JavaScrips.